Regain that vivid reality?

He no longer knew, wanting only quiet so the mass of her could
regain that vivid reality. Silently addressing her with a name not her own, he persevered to a realm beyond all personality.

it is an excerpt from the novel Fat City by Leonard Gardner.
They lay in bed, and he imagined another woman, then he touchs her wife and her wife says " you want to real bad"?
Regarding those sentences mentioned above, does this mean " he just wanted silence so he can feel her body without any disturbance"?
And about the second bolded sentence, does that mean " he says another name instead of her name so he doesn't restrict himself to his wife and fantasies about other women." ?

Seems somewhat turgid and prolix: "he persevered to a realm beyond all personality," does  not seem sensible to me. And, "regain that vivid reality," is self-contradictory: he wants an illusion, not reality. Maybe I just don't appreciate that work sufficiently

The above comment is a bit harsh, but it's certainly not easy to interpret without more knowledge about the characters' psychology and the events described, as well as the author's style, themes, and other info. This seems more a question of literary interpretation (Hi, literature SE!) unless you have a specific question about words or grammar.

I'm not familiar with the work you've quoted from, but given the context, I think I understand what is being said.
The man wants silence because it helps him imagine he's having sex with a different woman than his wife. Similarly, he can't speak his imagined lover's name out loud, because that would quite reasonably upset his very real wife.
Both the "mass of her" that had a "vivid reality" and the "realm beyond all personality" that you highlighted in your question refer to the man's imagination where he's having sex with the other woman, rather than the real world where he's with his wife instead.
